# Set select dropdown style to default

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I set border property in select element.

```
select {
   border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

IE7 doesn't support select styling. So now my requirement is to remove that style from all IE versions (7,8,9...) and make the dropdown as default. But this property works in above IE8. There is any css-only solution for this.

Note: I have specific IE class in html tag. can I use that in css like

```
.ie select {}
```

Comment: To target different versions of IE, you can use Conditionnal comments (but then it's not CSS only as you've got to modify HTML too) or CSS hacks. That said, it might be interresting to at least ask the question if such old versions of IE still should be supported.

Comment: in my case, I want default drop down for all IE version and red border on all other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below css hacks to specify IE restricted features. Hope those may help you! Give the red color border for all the browsers and set ne color for the IE browsers.

/* IE 11( Specific ) */

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  #selector {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}
```

/* IE 10( specific ) */

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  #selector {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}
```

/* IE 9( specific ) */

```
#selector {
  color: #000000; /* Ingeneral, for all browsers */
  color: #FFFFFF \0/IE9; /* Only for IE 9 */
}
```

/* IE 8( specific ) */

```
@media \0screen {
  #selector {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}
```

/* IE 7( specific and below version ) */

```
#selector {
  *color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: To remove the border you can use the below css.
**`border: none medium;`**.

Comment: I don't want any border. only the default as IE provide.

Comment: As the default styling if pretty difficult to get back. Still, please try to use the below and get some what like default.  
  
`**
select {  
border-bottom-color: #ccc;  
border-right-color: #ccc;  
border-width: 1px;  
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #000;  
}
**`

Comment: Once the default browser styling is being edited, it becomes very difficult to get that back, even sometimes impossible! I think the `box-shadow` may not work!  
So try to use through the hacks, may work!

Answer (score 0):

There are specific CSS hacks for IE, you can try those if you want like this:

**CSS**

```
select {
         border: 2px solid #0f0; /* for all browsers */
         border: 2px solid #000; /* IE8 and below */
         *border: 2px solid #000; /* IE7 and below  */
         _border: 2px solid #000; /* IE6 and below  */
}
```

Hacking your CSS may seem a quick fix for getting your styles to work across browser types, however, you should really be using conditional statements from within your HTML. e.g.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
Your IE8 and below HTML code here.
Perhaps importing a specific style sheet.
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The default IE style border.